# How to set up initial Core Data store in a Mac app?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, nsfilemanager

I am an experienced iOS developer trying to make my first Mac app. I want to use Core data to store the data in my app. In my iOS apps, I generally have a pre-created SQLite file which is used as the initial state of the data store, and which is moved into place on the first time the app is run, like this:

```
NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Datafile.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"Datafile-DefaultData" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (defaultStorePath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
    }
}
```

I want to do something similar in the mac app, except put the data in the `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp` directory. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4, the default Core Data project template, for some reason, uses the root `~/Library` directory (ie `~/Library/Application` to store your Core Data file. You should change this anyways (because it's a bad idea), but once you do that, it should work as you expect. I believe the default name on the Mac is `storedata`, and you should also note that you'll need to change the store type from XML, which is the default.

Comment: so, how do I change it away from `~/Library/Application` to something else?